# Testing Multisites with vagrant or Can I use multisite with only an IP address (without domain name)

Tags: multisite, server, subdomains

I'm testing multisite on a vm spun up by using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). I seem to be having trouble accessing multisite URLs. I've added them as such...

[image]

But when I attempt to visit them in the browser, I unfortunately see a 404 as such...

[image]

As directed, the contents of the .htaccess file are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And I've added the following block of code to `wp-config.php`:

```
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '192.168.33.10');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

If curious, the only options in my Vagrant file being used are:

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos64 vagrant]$ cat Vagrantfile  | grep -v \#

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "centos64-x86_64-20131030"
vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

Did I over look something? Is multisite possible with using a IP address and subdomains?

Comment: The 404 error you are seeing is from Apache.  Which means you either did not configure Apache's DocumentRoot properly or (more likely) you did not install WP in the proper directory.  From the info you provided, WP should be installed in <DocumentRoot>/test

Comment: The main site and /wp-admin come up just fine. /test is the first site I've added.

Comment: Hmm... hard to say then.  It is not an IP address problem at this point.  Possible problems - .htaccess file is not working or Apache is not allowing .htaccess file.  One way to see if your htaccess file is being process is by adding this line at the top 'deny from all'  Then access the site, you should get denied.

Comment: @user42826 You may want to move your comment to the answer field so I can mark that as correct. D'oh! Yes, the apache conf file was set to AllowOverride=None. I changed this. Things are much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error you are seeing is from Apache. Which means you  did not configure Apache properly.  It is not an IP address problem at this point. Possible problems - .htaccess file is not working or Apache is not allowing .htaccess file. One way to see if your htaccess file is being process is by adding this line at the top 'deny from all' Then access the site, you should get denied.

To enable htaccess in Apache httpd.conf add the AllowOverride directive

```
<Directory ..>
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: `AllowOverride None` *disables* `.htaccess` files. `AllowOverride All` (or `AllowOverride [directive-type [directive-type...]]`) will enable `.htaccess`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride .

Comment: Pat J - Thanks, that is what I get for cut-n-pasting!