# Can Multisite run without domain name in WordPress?

Tags: multisite

I have created Multisite in WordPress by using following details:

I have created a virtual host on XAMPP server as named mysite.local.

In hosts file, the path is C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.

```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       mysite.local
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf file, the path is C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs
    <Directory  "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite
    <Directory  "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the wp-config.php file, I have put.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.local/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.local/');



define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.local');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

This is working fine.

**Problem:** When I try to use multi-site without Virtual host then it stops working.

ex: http://localhost/mysite/

Question: Is it mandatory to create virtual host or domain for multi-site in WordPress?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. You could use http://localhost/mysite/ in WP_HOME WP_SITEURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with the help of following articles.

[Testing Multisites with vagrant or Can I use multisite with only an IP address (without domain name)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135487/testing-multisites-with-vagrant-or-can-i-use-multisite-with-only-an-ip-address?rq=1)

Actually, the issue was resolved by enabled .htaccess in httpd.conf file and edit the AllowOverride directive.

**From:**

```
<Directory ..>
    AllowOverride none   
</Directory>
```

**To:**

```
<Directory ..>
    AllowOverride All   
</Directory>
```